# How to redirect a url with a query to one that does not have a query

Tags: url, redirect, regex

I'm using Redirect Manager (https://github.com/rkingon/Craft-Plugin--Redirect-Manager) and I"m trying to redirect:
**www.website.com/?post_type=testimonials**

To:
**www.website.com/about-us**

I've tried the following regex rules with no success (hashes are needed for regex in redirect manager):

#^\?post_type=testimonials#

#^\?post_type=testimonials$#

#post_type=testimonials$#

All of them just stay on the homepage with the query appended when accessing the url. Any ideas on how to fix it or better ways of achieving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to the homepage template.

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('post_type') == "testimonials" %} 
   {% redirect "/about-us" %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I would prefer an option that allows to change this directly from the admin section, this does work and we may use it if we can't find a better solution :)